# Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.[ntext]

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, aggregate-functions

I am new to sql so sorry if the answer is obvious but i couldn't find it anywhere.
So i want to select the CategoryName,Description and the average price of the products that are in the same category.Below is the picture of the 2 tables involved.The problem is the description i cant find a way to show it.
(There are 8 categories and every category has 1 description)

[image]

This is the code I have made so far but it has the error:

```
SELECT  c.CategoryName,c.Description,avg(p.UnitPrice) 
FROM Categories AS c
INNER JOIN Products AS p ON c.CategoryID=p.CategoryID
GROUP BY c.CategoryName
```

The error:

```
Column 'Categories.Description' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Sorry for my bad english :/

Comment: the error is telling you your exact problem.  You have Description in the list next to select but you do not have it in your group by clause

Comment: I tried that too but because its ntext it says: The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Comment: the error about ntext and things would mean you are not allowed to group by it and it is a different error.  But solve it by casting the column in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` to a data type that you can aggregate such as `CAST(c.Description AS VARCHAR(???))` where ??? is an acceptable length or use `MAX`.

Comment: I tried that before but only put it on group by because thats how i saw it somewhere and didnt work but putting on select too it works!
Thanks a lot Matt, sorry for asking sth obvious.

Comment: What happens if you do the averaging in a CTE, like this?
`WITH CatAvgs as(
SELECT
    CategoryID 'catid',
    avg(UnitPrice) 'avgprice'
FROM Products
GROUP BY CategoryID
)
SELECT
    c.CategoryName,
    c.Description,
    a.avgprice
FROM CatAvgs a
INNER JOIN Categories c
ON c.CategoryID = a.catid`

Comment: Well that works too actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(n)text` can't be used in aggregate or window functions. It's also been deprecated since SQL Server 2008 (if I recall correctly, possibly 2005). You should really be using `(n)varchar(MAX)`.

If you really **"have"** to use `(n)text` then you'll need to do your aggregate first, and then retrieve the value of your `(n)text` column:

```
WITH Averages AS (
    SELECT p.CategoryID, avg(p.UnitPrice) AS AveragePrice
    FROM p.CategoryID
    GROUP BY p.CategoryID)
SELECT C.CategoryName, C.Description, A.AveragePrice
FROM Averages A
     JOIN Categories C ON A.CategoryID = C.CategoryID;
```

*(Note, this is untested due to lack of DDL and Sample Data)*

Comment: Problem was solved in the comments but thanks anyway !

Comment: @Larnu, I'm not sure the join is necessary in the CTE.

Comment: you mean using where? 
I am gonna accept your answer however because it works too.

Comment: @SQLCliff True, you could group by p.CategoryID and then complete outside the CTE. Would save the 2nd table lookup. I'll make an edit.